# Extracting layer output from Classification model of SimpleTransformer

Tags: python, text-classification, bert-language-model, simpletransformers

I have fine tuned a bert base model for text classification task. Now, I want to extract hidden layer output so as to combine this output with other features to train a random forest model.
Problem lies in the fact that I don't know how to extract hidden layer output. It would be really great if someone can help me out in this regard.

```
from simpletransformers.classification import ClassificationModel

model_xlm = ClassificationModel('bert', 'bert-base-uncased')
model_xlm.train_model(df_train)
```

Answer (score 0):

Ran across this in a Google search, and recently saw the answer to this by reading the source code in the SimpleTransformers git repo.

To get the hidden layer output, just pass **output_hidden_states** in to the model:

```
model_xlm = ClassificationModel('bert', 'bert-base-uncased', {"output_hidden_states": True})
```

then when you call predict, you will get this:

```
preds, model_outputs, all_embedding_outputs, all_layer_hidden_states = model.predict(data)
```

Here is the reference in the source:
https://github.com/ThilinaRajapakse/simpletransformers/blob/68f0faace15530fa1a738a34ea13521eec4518b1/simpletransformers/classification/classification_model.py#L2242